# Prevent propagation to event handler when calling this.checked in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 'select all' checkbox and I'm attempting to synchronize it with some other checkboxes on the page. If all of the other checkboxes are deselected then I want to deselect the 'select all' checkbox.

The problem is if you click one of the checkboxes twice the behavior is not as intended. I believe it is because when I call this.checked in the 'select all' event handler it is propagating to the other event handler. Is there a way to stop this from occurring?

JFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/te5cefxe/1/

```
<label class="checkbox"><input id="selectall" type="checkbox" checked> 
<span>Deselect All</span></label>
<br>
<label class="checkbox device"><input type="checkbox" name="number" value="1" checked>Choice 1</label>
<br>
<label class="checkbox device"><input type="checkbox" name="number" value="2" checked>Choice 2</label>


$(function(){
    $("#selectall").on('click', function(e) {
        var sa = this;
        $(sa).next().text(sa.checked ? 'Deselect All' : 'Select All');

        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
            if (this != sa) {
        // prevent the click event from propagating to the function below
                this.checked = sa.checked;
            }
        });
    });

    $("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function(e) {
        var ck = this;
        var sa = $("#selectall")[0];

        if (this != sa) {
            var dif = false;
            $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
                if (this != sa && (dif = !(this.checked == ck.checked))) {;
                    return false; // break out
                }
            });

            if (!dif) {
                console.log('same');
                sa.click();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: use `e.stopPropagation()`..

Comment: @acvcu i updated my answer check agian.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/te5cefxe/2/)**.

Use `e.stopPropagation()` Inside `each` method.

> **Description :** Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (this != sa && (dif = !(this.checked == ck.checked))) {;
        return false; // break out
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

> **e.stopPropagation()** is used to prevent event from bubbling up to DOM tree (toward the parents) where **e** is the event handler and **stopPropagation()** is javascript function.

**But** in your case you don't need that, there is problem in your `code`

Check the **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/jjxtrkrs/1/)**

**Or** the `Snippet` its working.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#selectall").on('change', function(e) {
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        $("#selectall + span").text("Deselect All");
    });

    $("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function(e) {
       var length = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").not("#selectall").length;
       if(length==0){
           $("#selectall").prop("checked",false);
           $("#selectall + span").text("Select All");
       } else if(length == 2){
           $("#selectall").prop("checked",true);
           $("#selectall + span").text("Deselect All");
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input id="selectall" type="checkbox" checked /><span>Deselect All</span></label>
<br>
<label class="checkbox device">
    <input type="checkbox" name="number" value="1" checked>Choice 1</label>
<br>
<label class="checkbox device">
    <input type="checkbox" name="number" value="2" checked>Choice 2</label>
```